# Spring WebFlow2 Javascript only working on first radio button

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

Spring WebFlow2 Javascript only working on first radio button

I am trying to use Spring JavaScript that comes with WebFlow2 to submitted my page with a transition value if the user clicks on one of the radio buttons.

I inserted my javascript on the page using onclick and onchange and it only works if the first radio button is selected.  I dont know why but I think I tried everything... can someone please tell me if this is a issue with Spring JavaScript.

JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Spring 3.0 MVC - Web Flow Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value="/resources/dojo/dojo.js" />">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring.js" />">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js" />">

</script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="<c:url value="/resources/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" />" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Customer Registration</h2>

    <form:form commandName="customer" id="customer">
        <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey"
            value="${flowExecutionKey}" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><font color=red><form:errors path="name" /></font><b>Name:
                </b></td>
                <td><form:input path="name" id="name" /> <script
                        type="text/javascript">
                    Spring
                            .addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration(
                                    {
                                        elementId : "name",
                                        widgetType : "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox",
                                        widgetAttrs : {
                                            promptMessage : "This is the name you would like entered into the system."
                                        }
                                    }));
                </script> <br />
                    <p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font color=red><form:errors path="phoneNumber" /></font>

                    <b>Phone number: </b></td>
                <td><form:input path="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" /><br />
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        Spring
                                .addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration(
                                        {
                                            elementId : "phoneNumber",
                                            widgetType : "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox",
                                            widgetAttrs : {
                                                promptMessage : "This is the phone number for the above name"
                                            }
                                        }));
                    </script></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Row:</b></td>
                <td><form:radiobutton value="B" path="row" id="rowBtn" />Row: B<BR>
                    <form:radiobutton value="A" path="row" id="rowBtn" />Row: A<BR>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
            Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.AjaxEventDecoration({
                elementId: "rowBtn",
                event: "onchange",
                formId:"customer",
                params: {fragments:"body", _eventId: "proceed"}
            }));
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.AjaxEventDecoration({
                elementId: "rowBtn",
                event: "onclick",
                formId:"customer",
                params: {fragments:"body", _eventId: "proceed"}
            }));
        </script>

        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Year of Birth:</td>
            <td>
            <form:select path="byear">
            <form:option value="2012" label="2012" />
            <form:option value="2011" label="2011" />
            <form:option value="2010" label="2010" />
            </form:select>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.AjaxEventDecoration({
                elementId: "byear",
                event: "onchange",
                formId:"customer",
                params: {fragments:"body", _eventId: "proceed"}
            }));
        </script>
        </td></tr>

        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="_eventId_proceed" value="proceed"
            id="proceed" />
            <input type="submit" name="_eventId_cancel" value="Cancel" />
    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
<form:radiobutton value="B" path="row" id="rowBtn" />Row: B<BR>
<form:radiobutton value="A" path="row" id="rowBtn" />Row: A<BR>
```

Your two radiobuttons have the same element id. 
The AjaxEventDecoration does a lookup based on that elementId. It assumes it is unique on the page and it does not expect multiple elements with the same id. You should give the second radiobutton another id.

You should probably just reenter the AjaxEventDecoration for that id as well.
If Spring.AjaxEventDecoration allows you to do something similar based on element class(instead of elementId) maybe you can do that, instead of duplicating the current Spring.AjaxEventDecoration snippet.